# Win7 CMD : For loop works independently, but not in a batch

Tags: batch-file

So here's the issue, this chunk of code works fine when I run it independently :

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%G in ('wmic desktopmonitor get screenheight^,screenwidth /value ^| find "="') do (
    if "%%G"=="ScreenHeight" set /a ResJ=%%H
    if "%%G"=="ScreenWidth" set /a ResI=%%H
)
echo Your screen width is %ResI%
echo Your screen height is %ResJ%
pause
```

However, when I insert it into this script I am working on, the variables remain blank:

```
if errorlevel 1 (
    cd base
    if exist %GameConfig% (
        gzdoom -config %GameConfig% -file %LevelA% %LevelB% %AddonA% %AddonB% %Patch% %HudA% %HudB% %HudC% %Music% -iwad %iWAD%
    ) else (
        for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%G in ('wmic desktopmonitor get screenheight^,screenwidth /value ^| find "="') do (
            if "%%G"=="ScreenHeight" set /a ResJ=%%H
            if "%%G"=="ScreenWidth" set /a ResI=%%H
        )
        echo Your screen width is %ResI%
        echo Your screen height is %ResJ%
        pause
        gzdoom -config %GameConfig% -width %ResI% -height %ResJ% -file %LevelA% %LevelB% %AddonA% %AddonB% %Patch% %HudA% %HudB% %HudC% %Music% -iwad %iWAD%
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You access the  variables inside a `()` block which means that even they are referenced further down in the code but the entire block is evaluated before the values are set.

- Solution 1: move the dependent code inside the loop and use the loop variables

  Also you can simplify the code by listing the values on one line and getting it via regexp `[0-9]`.

  ```dos
  for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in ('
      wmic desktopmonitor get screenheight^,screenwidth ^| findstr /r "[0-9]"
  ') do (
      gzdoom -config %GameConfig% -width %%b -height %%a ..............
  )
  ```
- Solution 2: don't use the outer `()` block, use `goto`

  ```dos
  if errorlevel 1 (
      if exist %GameConfig% ( ...... & goto done) else goto launch
  )
  :launch
      for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in ('
          wmic desktopmonitor get screenheight^,screenwidth ^| findstr /r "[0-9]"
      ') do set /a ResJ=%%a, ResI=%%b
      gzdoom -config %GameConfig% -width %ResI% -height %ResJ% ........
  :done
      exit /b
  ```
- Solution 3: use delayed expansion:

  ```dos
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  gzdoom -config %GameConfig% -width !ResI! -height !ResJ! ........
  endlocal
  ```

Comment: These are very good solutions, but the RegExp solution isn't suited for my needs, because I don't want the application to continue to be forced to launched at the desktop resolution once the resolution settings are set. My solution would be so simply move the bit of code up to before the choice branch, so that the variables are already ready by the time it's needed. This is what the resulting code looks like : http://pastebin.com/Kzx9NKR9