# Batch script prompt needs multiple entries

Tags: windows, batch-file

So I have this subroutine that I want to call from another location in a batch file.  The functions work as desired, but for some reason I cant pin down, the prompt wants to have the user enter something TWICE, before it will accept anything.

Say, if I enter "0", to go back to a previous menu, it takes me right back to the prompt, and I have to enter "0" again before it will actually go back to the previous menu (elsewhere in my main script).

I can, say, enter "w" (or any other value), then the second time, enter the one I actually WANT to use, and it will finally do it.

This is driving me nuts.

```
:subfullbackup
cls

if exist "%current%\Backup\Full_Backup" (
  Echo  Backup folder already exists
  Echo.
  Echo  [o]  Overwrite local device files with existing local files
  Echo  [w]  Wipe current local backup and start fresh
  Echo.
  set /p choice=Select: 


  if %choice% == o (
    Echo.
    Echo  Depending on how much data you have,
    Echo  this could take a couple hours.
    Echo.
    Echo  Backing up...
    adb pull /sdcard/ "%current%\Backup\Full_Backup" >nul 2>&1
    Echo.
    Echo  -= BACKUP COMPLETE =-
    Pause
    Goto :backup
  )


  if %choice% == w (
    Echo.
    Echo  Removing all current local backup files in 'Full_Backup'
    rmdir /S /Q "%current%\Backup\Full_Backup" >nul 2>&1
    Echo.
    Echo  Depending on how much data you have,
    Echo  this could take a couple hours.
    Echo.
    Echo  Backing up...
    adb pull /sdcard/ "%current%\Backup\Full_Backup" >nul 2>&1
    Echo.
    Echo  -= BACKUP COMPLETE =-
    Pause
    Goto :backup
  )


  if not %choice% == o goto subfullbackup
  if not %choice% == w goto subfullbackup
) else (
    Echo.
    Echo  Depending on how much data you have,
    Echo  this could take a couple hours.
    Echo.
    Echo  Backing up...
    adb pull /sdcard/ "%current%\Backup\Full_Backup" >nul 2>&1
    Echo.
    Echo  -= BACKUP COMPLETE =-
    Pause
    Goto :backup
)
Goto :eof
```

Comment: `%Variables%` inside `()` block are expanded before the entire block is executed, so on the first run `if not %choice% == o goto subfullbackup` goes to the beginning and displays the prompt again. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33817417/3959875)

Comment: [maybe a bit better to understand](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)

Answer (score 1):

Your batch code with using delayed expansion, enabled at top of the batch script with command **setlocal** which additionally creates a copy of all environment variables and remembering also current directory for restoring the variables list, current directory and current states of command extensions and delayed expansion on **endlocal** or leaving batch processing:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "current=%CD%"

:FullBackup
cls

if exist "%current%\Backup\Full_Backup" (
  Echo  Backup folder already exists
  Echo.
  Echo  [o]  Overwrite local device files with existing local files
  Echo  [w]  Wipe current local backup and start fresh
  Echo.
  set "UserChoice="
  set /p "UserChoice=Select: "


  if /I "!UserChoice!" == "o" (
    Echo.
    Echo  Depending on how much data you have,
    Echo  this could take a couple hours.
    Echo.
    Echo  Backing up...
    adb.exe pull /sdcard/ "%current%\Backup\Full_Backup" >nul 2>&1
    Echo.
    Echo  -= BACKUP COMPLETE =-
    Pause
    Goto DoBackup
  )


  if /I "!UserChoice!" == "w" (
    Echo.
    Echo  Removing all current local backup files in 'Full_Backup'
    rmdir /S /Q "%current%\Backup\Full_Backup" >nul 2>&1
    Echo.
    Echo  Depending on how much data you have,
    Echo  this could take a couple hours.
    Echo.
    Echo  Backing up...
    adb.exe pull /sdcard/ "%current%\Backup\Full_Backup" >nul 2>&1
    Echo.
    Echo  -= BACKUP COMPLETE =-
    Pause
    Goto DoBackup
  )

  goto FullBackup

) else (
    Echo.
    Echo  Depending on how much data you have,
    Echo  this could take a couple hours.
    Echo.
    Echo  Backing up...
    adb.exe pull /sdcard/ "%current%\Backup\Full_Backup" >nul 2>&1
    Echo.
    Echo  -= BACKUP COMPLETE =-
    Pause
    Goto DoBackup
)
Goto :EOF

:DoBackup
```

But your batch code could be also written without delayed expansion and much more compact avoiding duplicate code lines:

```
@echo off
set "current=%CD%"

:FullBackup
cls

if exist "%current%\Backup\Full_Backup" goto PromptBackup

:OverwriteBackup
Echo.
Echo  Depending on how much data you have,
Echo  this could take a couple hours.
Echo.
Echo  Backing up...
adb.exe pull /sdcard/ "%current%\Backup\Full_Backup" >nul 2>&1
Echo.
Echo  -= BACKUP COMPLETE =-
Pause
Goto DoBackup

:PromptBackup
Echo  Backup folder already exists
Echo.
Echo  [o]  Overwrite local device files with existing local files
Echo  [w]  Wipe current local backup and start fresh
Echo.
set "UserChoice="
set /p "UserChoice=Select: "

if /I "%UserChoice%" == "o" goto OverwriteBackup

if /I not "%UserChoice%" == "w" goto FullBackup

Echo.
Echo  Removing all current local backup files in 'Full_Backup'
rmdir /S /Q "%current%\Backup\Full_Backup" >nul 2>&1
goto OverwriteBackup

:DoBackup
```

Some notes about small changes in code:

1. [choice](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) (SS64 article) is a standard Windows command. Therefore it is advisable to avoid [choice](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732504.aspx) (Microsoft  article) as name for an environment variable or label. `UserChoice` (CamelCase spelling for easier reading) is used instead of **choice**.
2. [backup](http://ss64.com/sql/backup.html) (SS64 article) is not a standard Windows command, but a standard SQL command. Therefore it is also advisable to avoid **backup** as name for an environment variable or label. `DoBackup` is used instead in batch code above.
3. It is advisable to define a default for an environment variable before prompting a user. The user can hit just <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> in which case the environment variable keeps its value.

   The environment variable is cleared with `set "UserPoint="` before prompting the user and therefore the variable does not exist when user enters nothing.

   Possible would be also `set "UserPoint=o"` or `set "UserPoint=w"` to define a valid default value.
4. Comparing strings with user input should be done always with using double quotes to avoid an exit of batch processing caused by a syntax error when user inputs nothing.

   `if %choice% == w (` becomes `if == w (` when the user enters nothing which is a syntax error and results in breaking batch processing by command processor.

   `if /I "%UserChoice%" == "w" (` becomes `if /I "" == "w"` when the user enters nothing in code above which is still valid batch code and can be therefore processed.

   **Note:** User could now break batch processing by entering `"w"`.
   But it can be expected here that the user does not input 1 or more double quotes on being asked for `o` or `w`.
5. On comparing strings entered by user with predefined strings it is advisable to do case-insensitive string comparisons if letters are included in the compared strings.

   The option `/I` changes a string comparison from case-sensitive to case-insensitive.

   So now the user can enter also `O` or `W` and this is interpreted like `o` or `w`.